# Load parts of large image fast in Java

Tags: java, image

I have an application that need to show a very large image (from a png on disk) with only a small part of the image is visible on screen at any time. However the visible section can move quickly around the large image.

Loading the whole image into a BufferedImage at once is not a good idea as it can be 10 000 - 100 000 pixels wide, but the size on disk is not very large (a few MB perhaps) so it is a question of loading only the relevant sections to be displayed.

I've tried creating an ImageReader like this:

```
FileImageInputStream is = new FileImageInputStream(imageFile);
ImageReader imageReader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(is).next();
ImageReader.setInput(is, false, true);
ImageReadParam readParameters = imageReader.getDefaultReadParam();
```

And then a method for getting a subimage something like this:

```
private BufferedImage loadFrame(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    readParameters.setSourceRegion(new Rectangle(x,y,w,h));
    try {
        return imageReader.read(0, readParameters);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This works in principle, but it is far too slow. So when moving fast around the image it lags way too much.

I also tried splitting up the source image beforehand so I had a bunch of smaller images on disk that I then loaded as needed using `ImageIO.read(getImageFile(x,y))` where `getImageFile(x,y)` would return the appropriate `File` for that location. This method was actually much faster and fully usable.

So I guess I have a way to make this work, but it just seems a bit awkward to do it this way. Besides needing some preparation of the source image, it also requires a lot of disk access (although I guess this is probably buffered somewhere).

So my question is: What would be the best way to do this? (And why is it faster to load an image from disk than to load a part of an image from an ImageReader?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PNG is a compressed format, you can't just open the file and seek to a specific location to start reading the region (like you can with a bitmap ~after reading the file header of course). The whole PNG needs to be loaded (parsed/decompressed) before you can start extracting regions of it. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header)

If you want to sacrifice disk space to improved memory (RAM) usage and performance...

- You can divide the image up and load only those grid chunks that you need to build the view for the user.
- - 1x1.png, 1x2.png, 2x1.png, 2x2.png - if the user is looking at the top left corner you only need to load 1x1.png etc etc.
- You can convert the image to a bitmap BMP the image will be much larger on the disk, but you'll be able to extract specific regions of it without having to process the whole file.

Comment: OK. I guess I thought it would be possible to decompress only a part of an PNG, but thinking about it I guess that it wouldn't be easy or efficient to design a compression format that would work like that (and obviously PNG is not such a format). Thanks for your answer!